# RabbitMQ as both Producer and Consumer in a single application

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am currently learning RabbitMQ and AMQP in general. I started working with some tutorials I found online and all of them show more or less the same example - a Spring Boot web app that, upon a REST call, produces a message and puts in onto a RabbitMQ queue and then, another class from the same app, which is configured as the Consumer of that message consumes it and processes the handler method.

I can't wrap my head around why this is beneficial in any way. The upside I understand is that the handler is executed in a separate thread, while the controller method can return right after sending the message to the queue. However, why would this be in any way better than just using Spring's `@Async` annotation on that handler method and calling it explicitly? In that case I suppose we would achieve the same thing, while not having to host and manage a seperate instance of a message broker like RabbitMQ.

Can someone please explain? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply:

1. with RabbitMq you can have persistent messages and a much safer and consistent exception management. In case the machine crashes, already pushed messages are not lost.
2. A message can be pushed to an exchange and consumed by more parallel consumers, that helps scaling the application in case the consumer code is too slow.

and a lot of other reasons...

Comment: How does rabbit know which consumer instance to push the message to? Does it know when threads are available?

Comment: Additonal question: would it be a valid use case to use Rabbit in my app for mailing? I mean - upon user registration I send a message to rabbit queue to send a welcome email to my new user. Then in the same app I have a listener to that message, that actually performs the email sending. I set rabbit retry count to 3 and if it fails I put it in the Dead Letter Queue to analyze manually in the console. Is this a  valid use case and one that makes sense?

Comment: Sure, it's a perfect use case!

Comment: Regarding your first question, if more consumer are consuming the same queue, you can't predict which consumer will actually consume the next incoming message. Anyway, multiple consumer can consume the same queue in a parallel way.